# Eclipse not showing Terminated message or finished code in console to understand program execution finished

Tags: eclipse, console

I am executing program which is finished successfully. but now message displayed in console to understand this program execution finished and console cursor placing wrong places. please assist on this issue.

I want some message display in console after execution finished or terminated like Finish code exit 0 something

what to do for this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YUQg.png)

Comment: Do you see more if you widen the Console view?

Comment: I dont know how to edit this question because wrong sentence in first paragraph. It should be below //I am executing program which is finished successfully. but no message displayed in console to understand this program execution finished. and another issue console cursor placing wrong places. please assist on this issue.//